# Как получить фото контактов whatsapp?

Tags: android

Возможно ли получить фото контактов whatsapp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatsapp не предоставляет доступа к api для получения фото контактов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Получается только вариант, сохранять фото профиля в ручную и затем забирать?

Comment: Да, иного варианта нету

Comment: А у меня и этот вариант не проходит...у меня вообще не высвечивается три точки на которых есть функция сохранить фото контакта в ватс аппе что тогда делать Подскажите пожалуйста...